# eoslime: Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations

Tags: eosjs, unit-tests

When Trying to run my test with

```
eoslime test
```

and calling

```
eoslime.Contract.deploy(...., ....)
```

I get

Error: the string "{\"code\":500,\"message\":\"Internal Service Error\",\"error\":{\"code\":3090003,\"name\":\"unsatisfied_authorization\",\"what\":\"Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations\",\"details\":[{\"message\":\"transaction declares authority '{\\"actor\\":\\"eosio\\",\\"permission\\":\\"active\\"}', but does not have signatures for it under a provided delay of 0 ms, provided permissions [], provided keys [\\"EOS7CZHcDrT6E4sWfSzjUQAM4NGyVkfH6La1QXqQPT1q2zc2NkEYB\\"], and a delay max limit of 3888000000 ms\",\"file\":\"authorization_manager.cpp\",\"line_number\":532,\"method\":\"check_authorization\"}]}}" was thrown, throw an Error :)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)

I have set

```
eoslime.Provider.defaultAccount.privateKey = "...";
eoslime.Provider.defaultAccount.publicKey = "...";
```

But anyway this happens. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What is the name of the account you are deploying with? If it is not eosio, please also set the `defaultAccount.name`. If it is eosio, please check if the keys you are providing, are the keys of the eosio account